# RegEx: How Can I match whitespace except HTML code in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I just have a question.

Using Regex in JS, How can I match whitespace except HTML tag?
I mean there are many whitespace, but I don't want whitecpase in HTML tag.

Here is example HTML Code.

```
<b>Welcome to StackOverflow</b>
<br></br>
<br></br>

<b>Hello</b><em>Friends</em>

<asdfasd>Thanks for looking at this regex</asdfsadfsd>
```

expected result:
    [I want to match this blue background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gemqf.png)

I use this regex code.

> />([^<]*)

but I don't know how can I match a whitespace.

Link for test: http://regexr.com/3e07o

Please explain me.

Comment: ask [tony the pony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: seriously - follow the link down the rabbit hole